# How to display a popup when clicks the link in the header?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, popup

In my header provide a link for adding new client. When click the add client link display a popup window that contain a textbox and a submit button.When i click the link display popup window fully fade in(shaded) and not display the label

Whats wrong here?

**header**

```
 <a data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true" data-toggle="modal" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#addClientPop" <?php if($home_index== 1) { ?> class="active" <?php } ?>></span>
  Add Client<span class="arrow"></span>
                            </a> 

<div id="addClientPop" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                                                <h3>Add Client</h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <div class="scroller" style="height:75px" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="1">
                                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                                        <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label">Client Name</label>
                                                            <div class="controls">
                                                                <input id="client_name" name="client_name" class="client_box" type="text" class="form-control" required >                                                                                                    
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>   
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">     
                                                <button onClick="submit_client();" type="button" class="btn blue">Submit</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Is this not working ? Are there any errors in the console ?

Comment: no error display the popup window thats fully shaded and display the tectbox and submit button not show the label

Comment: You wanna display a popup but I don't see any `window.open` or `prompt` in your code

Comment: display the popup but some issues

Comment: Just add `onclick="return prompt('New client', 'Ex : Edoird');"` in your `<a`. Is that what you want ?

Comment: try this data-target="#addClientPop.no popup displayed but fully shaded

Comment: Did you checked if the text color is just white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution i have worked well[image]

`<a data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true" data-toggle="modal" class="dropdown-toggle active" href="#addClientPop" >
    Add Client<span class="arrow"></span>
</a>`

`<div id="addClientPop" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h3>Add Client</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="scroller" style="height:75px" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="1">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Client Name</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="client_name" name="client_name" class="client_box" type="text" class="form-control" required >

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button onClick="submit_client();" type="button" class="btn blue">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: Ya same code i have run. good. You can Flag and Promote Our Answer as True. :)

Comment: Good, In future for any doubt please make Your Problem more http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ya explain your problem with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example;

Answer (score 0):

In your code what i have noticed that you have closed `</span>` tag in `<a>` and if($home_index==1) then `class` attribute is going to be add two times.

It should be like:

`<a data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true" data-toggle="modal"  class="dropdown-toggle <?php if($home_index== 1) { echo 'active';}?>" href="#addClientPop">Add Client <span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span> </a>`

Comment: same effect as previous

Comment: Use `class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"`

Comment: not working the link.the same code i used  above in another page thats working

Comment: Once again remove class="active" in php script; I belive class atributes two times doesn't make any sense. Rather than calling onclick event try by data-toggle

Comment: mainly you have not added : `<div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">`

Comment: I have no longer access to chat application of Stack Exchange; Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
                 <li>
                  <a data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true" data-toggle="modal" class="dropdown-toggle active" href="#addPop" >
Add Client<span class="arrow"></span>
                  </a>

           <div id="addPop" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h3>Add Client</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="scroller" style="height:75px" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="1">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Client Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="market_price" name="market_price" class="client_box" type="text" class="form-control" required >

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <button onClick="submit_price();" type="button" class="btn blue">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </li>
```